# What the best way to store value one time and reuse it

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my default page, I take the user name and role, and I want to reuse it in all other pages. What the best practice to access this user name and role in every page. Is seesion the only solution for this or there is another way?

Comment: See this overview for all available options: [ASP.NET State Management Recommendations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can either store that information in a **Session** or a **Cookie**. Both are served to store user-information data and have their pros and cons.

To read more about sessions & cookies, use the following links:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As you need user name and roles It will be already stored in some of the variables. Like User.Identity in MVC application. I would suggest to use already available data instead of storing it again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one good solution exists.

You can make one class with getter and setter method of username and role within same namespace. ex.

```
public class UserData
{
    public string UserName{ set; get; }
    public string Role { set; get; }
}
```

and now you can get and set value of both(username and role).
like,

```
//Set both properties
UserData objUserData = new UserData();
objUserData.UserName = "set_user_name_you_want";
objUserData.Role = "set_role_you_want";
```

Now you can get that both properties anywhere you want within that same namespace.

```
//Get both properties
UserData objUserData = new UserData();
String UserName = objUserData.UserName;
String Role = objUserData.Role;
```

I hope this will helpful to  you! :)

Comment: Can you explain more please, is there any tutorial for your idea

Comment: yes Check this example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/615499/Models-POCO-Entity-Framework-and-Data-Patterns

Comment: if I set the value of UserName in page 1 , I will not be able to access the value of UserName in page 2 even if they both have same namespace!